# A question about choice of signs in expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $ f_1,...,f_N $ a collection of fucntions, $ \epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_N$ randomized signs ( $\pm1$) with same probability and $ N\in\mathbb{N}$.

If
$ A\|(\sum_{k=1}^{N}|f_k|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|_q^q\leqslant \mathbb{E}(\| \sum_{k=1}^{N}\epsilon_kf_k \|_q^q)\leqslant B\|(\sum_{k=1}^{N}|f_k|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|_q^q$,  $\mathbb{E}$ denotes expectation, $A$ and $B$ constants they depend only on $q$.

I would like to understand why I can say that there is a choice of signs ( $\epsilon_k's$) such that $ \widetilde{A}\|(\sum_{k=1}^{N}|f_k|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|_q^q\leqslant\| \sum_{k=1}^{N}\epsilon_kf_k \|_q^q$.

Comment: What is $\tilde A$ ?

Comment: a constant they depend only on q

Comment: Why are there both subscripts and superscripts which are $q$?

Comment: @coffeemath, I assume one takes the $q$-norm to the power $q$.

Comment: But when $\tilde A$ is very large, we cannot be sure that we can choose the $\epsilon_k'$ in a good way, because the right hand side has a maximum, but the left hand side hasn't if $\tilde A$ is not specified.